# TypeScript generics skip types

Tags: typescript

The type definition of a library (in this case `react-query`) looks like this:

```
export function useQuery<TResult, TKey extends AnyQueryKey, TError = Error>({
  queryKey,
  queryFn,
  config,
}: {
  queryKey: TKey
  queryFn?: QueryFunction<TResult, TKey>
  config?: QueryOptions<TResult, TError>
}): QueryResult<TResult, TError>
```

As we can see, the function is using 3 generic types (`TResult`, `TKey` and `TError`).

`TResult` and `TKey` are inferred automatically and that's awesome because we never have to type them manually.

However, I'm using a custom error class in my app and that's why I need to specify `TError`.

Of course, I'd like to do that **without** breaking the automatic inferring since that would result in unnecessary and annoying boilerplate in my code.

So my question is:

Can we skip specifying types like we can do with optional function parameters?

Comment: No, TypeScript doesn't support partially supplying generic type parameters (see e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe. If you'd like to write an answer, I'll accept it.